# Let $M$, $N$, $L$ be midpoints of $AB$, $BC$, $AD$. If $CL\parallel AB$ and $NQ\parallel ML$, find the area of $ABCD$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

> Let $M$, $N$, and $L$ be the midpoints of $AB$, $BC$ and $AD$, respectively.  Suppose that $CL\parallel AB$.  A point $Q$ on $CL$ is such that $NQ\parallel ML$.    Calculate the area of ​the quadrangular region $ABCD$ as a function of areas $\Bbb A$, $\Bbb B$, $\Bbb C$.
>
> [image: Question Picture]

I tried in so many ways but I couldn' isolate this area in terms of $\Bbb A$, $\Bbb B$, and $\Bbb C$, because I coudn't list the area [CLD] with the areas $\Bbb A$, $\Bbb B$, and $\Bbb  C$.

The answer is
$$[ABCD]=8(\Bbb A+\Bbb B-\Bbb C).$$
I tried to draw AN and divide the areas A and B in $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$, and I got the equations:
$$A_2+B_1+H=D,$$
$$A_1+B_2+F=C+G+E.$$
How can I do this?

[image: My attempt]

Comment: What have you tried exactly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: You asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3636272/721644) 8 days ago.

Comment: I was thinking about this for a while and tried to search for the task by image, so I found it originally in Portugese. Maybe we should focus on the altitudes.

Comment: Some basic information we definitely know is $\measuredangle BAL=\measuredangle CLD$ and $\measuredangle LAM=\measuredangle MLC=\measuredangle NQC$. I drew such quadrilateral in GeoGebra, so I saw it doesn' t have to be cyclic. We could find the ratio $\frac{|LM|}{NQ|}$.

Comment: Let $a_1$ be the altitude of $\Delta ALM$, $a_1\perp\overline{AL}$ and $a_2$ be the altitude of $\Delta LDC$, $a_2\perp\overline{AD}$. $\frac{\operatorname{Area}(\Delta ALM)}{\operatorname{Area}(\Delta LDC)}=\frac{a_1}{a_2}$. Let $c_1\perp\overline{ML}$ be the altitude of the triangle with  area $\Bbb C$. Then $\operatorname{Area}(MLNQ)=\frac{|ML|+|NQ|}{2}c_1$.

Comment: Notice, e.g.,  $\operatorname{Area}(\Delta NBL)=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta QML)$. Actually, you have already noticed the similar thing: $\operatorname{Area}(\Delta ALC)=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta LDC)$ and $\operatorname{Area}(\Delta ANB)=\operatorname{Area}(\Delta ACN)$.

Comment: Where did you get all these weird area problems?  I found them to be quite unusual.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $P=ML\cap AN$, $E=CL\cap DB$, $F=AN\cap BD$, and $R=AE\cap PL$.  Because $AB\parallel CL$ and $L$ biescts $AD$, $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$.  Since $M$ is a midpoint of $AB$, $ME\parallel AD$.  Therefore, $\square ALEM$ is a parallelogram.  Therefore, the diagonals $AE$ and $ML$ bisect each others.  Hence, $R$ is a midpoint of $AE$.  As $N$ is a midpoint of $BC$ and $AB\parallel CL$, we see that $NR\parallel AB$.  Therefore,
$$[MNA]=[MRA].$$
This shows that
$$\Bbb C=[MPN]=[MNA]-[MPA]=[MRA]-[MPA]=[APR].$$

We then have
$$[ARL]=[APL]-[APR]=\Bbb A-\Bbb C.$$
Note that $\triangle ARL\sim\triangle AED$ because $BD\parallel ML$ ($M$ and $L$ are midpoints of $AB$ and $AD$).  Therefore,
$$\frac{[ARL]}{[AED]}=\left(\frac{AL}{AD}\right)^2=\frac14.$$
Since $ED=EB$, we get
$$[AEB]=[AED].$$
So
$$[ABD]=[AEB]+[AED]=2[AED]=2\cdot 4[ARL]=8(\Bbb A-\Bbb C).$$

Note that $\triangle CNQ\sim \triangle CBE$ because $BD\parallel ML$ and $ML\parallel NQ$, so
$$\frac{[CNQ]}{[CBE]}=\left(\frac{CN}{CB}\right)^2=\frac14.$$
Since $L$ bisects $AD$ and $CL\parallel AB$, $E$ also bisects $BD$.  Therefore
$$[CBE]=[CED].$$
Hence
$$[BCD]=[CBE]+[CED]=2[CBE]=2\cdot 4[CNQ]=8\Bbb B.$$
That is,
$$[ABCD]=[ABD]+[BCD]=8(\Bbb A-\Bbb C)+8\Bbb B=8(\Bbb A+\Bbb B-\Bbb C).$$

---

If all else fails, you can use assign coordinates to the problem.  WLOG, let $A=(0,0)$, $L=(2,0)$, $D=(4,0)$, $M=(0,1)$, and $B(0,2)$.  We can do this because area ratios are preserved under affine transformations.

If $C=(2,2c)$, then $N=(1,c+1)$.  Since $NQ\parallel ML$, $NQ$ is given by the linear equation
$$y-c-1=-\frac{1}{2}(x-1).$$
So $Q=\left(2,c+\frac12\right)$.  The line $ML$ is 
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$$
and the line $AN$ is
$$y=(c+1)x.$$
If $P=AN\cap ML$, then
$$P=\left(\frac{2}{2c+3},\frac{2c+2}{2c+3}\right).$$

We have
$$[APL]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2c+2}{2c+3}\cdot 2=\frac{2c+2}{2c+3},$$
$$[CNQ]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1\cdot\left(2c-c-\frac12\right)=\frac{2c-1}{4},$$
and
$$[MPN]=\frac12\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&1\\
1&\frac{2}{2c+3}&\frac{2c+2}{2c+3}\\
1&1&c+1
\end{array}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2c+1}{2c+3}\right).$$
This means $2[APL]-2[MPN]=1$ and $c=2[CNQ]+\frac12$.
However,
$$[ABCD]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot (2+2c)+\frac12\cdot 2\cdot 2c=2+2c+2c=4c+2.$$
That is
$$[ABCD]=4\left(2[CNQ]+\frac12\right)+2=8[CNQ]+4=8[CNQ]+4\big(2[APL]-2[MPN]\big).$$
Hence
$$[ABCD]=8[APL]+8[CNQ]-8[MPN]=8\Bbb A+8\Bbb B-8\Bbb C.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Given the midpoints M, L and N, we have ML || BD || NQ and ML = BT = $2$NQ. Construct NP || AB || CL to have the similar $\triangle$AME and $\triangle$NEP, as well as all the equal segment lengths $x$, $y$ and $z$ indicated in the diagram. Then,

$$\frac{EM}{x-EM}= \frac y{y+z} \implies \frac{EM}x = \frac{y}{2y+z},\>\>\>\frac{EL}x= \frac{3y+2z}{2y+z}$$

Let [.] denote areas and evaluate $\Bbb A$, $\Bbb B$ and $\Bbb C$ in terms of $[ABD]$ and $[CBD]$

\begin{align}
\Bbb A & = \frac{EL}{ML} [AML] =\frac{EL}{2x} \cdot\frac14[ABD] = \frac{3y+2z}{8(2y+z)} [ABD] \\
\Bbb B & = \frac14 [CBT] = \frac18 [CBD]  \\
\Bbb C & = \frac{EM}{PM} [NMP] = \frac{EM}{x}\cdot\frac12[NPLQ] = 
\frac{EM}{2x}([NGTQ]+[PLTG]) \\
&\hspace{0cm}=\frac{y}{2(2y+z)}(\frac14[CBD]+\frac14[ABD])
=\frac{y}{8(2y+z)} ([CBD]+[ABD])
\end{align}

Then

$$\Bbb A + \Bbb B - \Bbb C 
= \frac{y+z}{8(2y+z)} (2[ABD] + [CBD] ) $$

Recognize $\frac yz = \frac{[ABD]}{[CBD]}$ and substitute it into above equation to obtain

$$\Bbb A + \Bbb B - \Bbb C 
= \frac18 ([ABD] + [CBD] ) = \frac18 [ABCD] $$

Answer (score -2):

Angles $BAD$ and $ABC$ are arbitraries so if the required relation is non constant then the problem is not determined. Consequently in order to verify the relation $[ABCD]=8(\Bbb A+\Bbb B-\Bbb C)$ we choose a convenient quadrilateral for easy calculation.

Let the trapezoid $ABCD$ where $A=(0,0),\space B=(0,2a)\space C=(a,2a)\space D=((2a,0)$ We have $M=(0,a),\space L=(a,0)\space N=(\dfrac a2,2a)$ and $CL\parallel AB$.

$AN$ and $ML$ determine a point of intersection $R=(\dfrac a5,\dfrac{4a}{5})$ and the point $Q=(a,\dfrac {3a}{2})$ is given by intersection of $CL$ and $NQ$.

With this triangles $NQC$ and $ARL$ clearly have an area of $\dfrac{a^2}{8}$ and $\dfrac{2a^2}{5}$ respectively and usually calculation gives the other shadow triangle $MNR$ has an area equal to $\dfrac{3a^2}{20}$.

Now $$8( \dfrac{2a^2}{5}+\dfrac{a^2}{8}-\dfrac{3a^2}{20})=\dfrac{8\cdot15a^2}{40}=3a^2$$

This $3a^2$ is precisely the area of the trapezoid.

[image]

Comment: You would be correct if there is an assumption that $BC\parallel AD$.  There isn't.  A lot of generality is lost.

Comment: Furthermore, I could use the same method as your proof to show that $[ABCD]=10\Bbb A+16\Bbb B-20\Bbb C$, and this can be easily shown to be false.

Comment: (2) If you have the values of $A,B$ and $C$ then there are infinitely many coefficients $a,b$ and $c$ such that $[ABCD]=aA+bB+cC$. I repeat,you do have a deficient mathematical criteria.

Comment: Have you even looked at other solutions?  You don't have to look at mine.  Look at Quanto's.  If you suppose $[ABCD]=a\Bbb A+b\Bbb B+c\Bbb C$ in that solution, it can be shown that $a=8$, $b=8$, and $c=-8$.  In your solution, there is not enough information to find the values of $a,b,c$.  Do you always impolitely respond to criticisms ?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, but you are utterly rude.  I am sorry you feel this way.

Comment: Anyone who does not believe in my reasoning to solve this problem should also not believe in the answers given by Wolfram or anyone else about whether or not a 20-digit number is a prime. Indeed, the primality tests used are probabilistic and not deterministic. So also the probability of failing with the proposition is almost nil choosing an arbitrary quadrilateral.

Comment: If your reasoning is sound then no problem. But you assumed in your soln that $ABCL$ is a rectangle.  That means - no matter how you use affine transformation, the original $ABCL$ is a parallelogram.  The question doesn't assume this.  We only know $AB\parallel CL$ not $AC\parallel AL$.  I tried my best to explain why generality is lost.

Comment: @WE Tutorial School.- Sorry dear friend, my last comment was addressed to the MSE reading community and not to you. Good luck. ( Could you tell me when I am using the 90 degree fact? Sure but it would be totally analogous when using another angle with the not-so-gentle trigonometric functions only).

Comment: Look at your coordinates $A(0,0), B(0,2a),C(a,2a),L(a,0)$.  What does $\square ABCL$ look like?

Comment: Again misunderstanding. I am not talking about the figure's shape but about the reasoning used.This is my last comment here. Good luck dear friend.Let's obey the editor's note.